# Z3 Installation issue on windows 10

Tags: linux, ocaml, z3, ocamlfind

I am trying to install Z3 package(https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3.git)
I ran the following commands

```
./configure
cd build
make 
make install
```

Installation was successfull. However when i run

```
Ocamlfind list
```

z3 component is not listed. So when i try to build my project which uses z3  , its failing with error

> ocamlfind: Package `Z3' not found.

I did the following workarounds,
a) added the z3.exe location to path
b) I ran the following python command, but i got an error message saying its not able to locate ocamlopt.exe path.

```
python scripts/mk_make.py --python.
```

Please provide some direction. I'm new to Ocaml and linux

Comment: To enable the OCaml bindings, you want to add `--ml` to the call to `scripts/mk_make.py`. If it complains about `ocamlopt` not being found, something is wrong with your OCaml setup, or you may have to use the `OCAML...` (like `OCAMLOPT`) environment variables to tell it where your OCaml lives.

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger I have created the environment variable. I tried with --ml. Im still facing the same issue.

Comment: How did you install OCaml?

Comment: I installed using OPAM package for windows.