# Ocalmlfind cannot find Z3 package

Tags: ocaml, z3, ocamlfind

I have installed z3 package from here https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3.git 
However ocamlfind is not able for find it.

if i run which z3, it lists where the component is installed.
However, Ocamlfind is not able to find it.

Steps followed to install Z3

```
python ./scripts/mk_make.py --ml --prefix=D:/winz3 -g
cd build
make 
make install
```

Comment: Can you share the steps you followed for installing z3?

Comment: @xennygrimmato I have updated the installation steps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Z3 Installation issue on windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54179239/z3-installation-issue-on-windows-10)